# Class not found with composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I have my file structure as

```
/
/app/
/app/logs/
/app/templates/
/app/index.php
/public_html/
/public_html/.htaccess
/public_html/index.php
/vendor
/vendor/(all vendor here)
```

My vhost is pointing to /public_html

in app/Index.php

```
namespace App;

class Index {}
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload":
{
    "psr-0":
    {
        "App\\":  "app/"
    }
}
```

Yet it is still showing as ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'App\Index' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\public_html\index.php on line 34

Line 34:

```
new \App\Index();
```

Using Slimframework as well if that matters, can't think what is wrong

Comment: It seems psr-0 failed, changing it to psr-4 works :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you were using the PSR-0 standard, PHP was looking for the file `app/App/Index.php`, which does not exist. Note that in PSR-0, you define a base directory (`app` in your case) where the mapped namespace (`App`) can be found. However, the file structure within that base directory should exactly match the fully qualified class names. So class `App\FooBar` should be in the file `app/App/FooBar.php`. Note that `app` is the base directory, and `App` is the directory that contains all subdirectories and PHP files for that namespace.

Since this is not the case in your application (and also because PSR-0 has been deprecated), you should (as you already did) use PSR-4, the new autoloading standard, instead. In PSR-4, you can directly map a certain namespace to a certain directory. In your case, you have mapped the `App` namespace to the `app` directory, so that PHP will open the `app/Index.php` file if you need to use the `App\Index` class.